# How to find Table contents (Paypal transaction) in YII framework

Tags: php, html, yii, paypal, transactions

I am working in Yii Frame Work and also working in pay-pal transaction.I already shown payment transaction Detail in my admin panel.

Here My screenshot
[image: Here My Transaction]

I got a  ID,UserID and Customer where it came from.
But my problem is, How to get Table content `<tr><td>` in that transaction table.

Here my view page for Depositor

```
<?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView', array(
'id'=>'deposit-grid',
'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
'filter'=>$model,
    'ajaxUpdate'=>false,
'columns'=>array(   
'id',
'user_id',
        array(
            'header' => 'Customer',
            'name' => 'customer',
            'value' => '$data->user->name1." ".$data->user->name2." (".$data->user->email.")"',
        ),
'deposit',
'memo',  
'created',
'modified',
array(
'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonColumn',
            'template' => '{view}',
),
),
)); ?>
```

Here my code contains   `'value' => '$data->user->name1." ".$data->user->name2." (".$data->user->email.")"',` is result like above table.

**Updated:**

Here I need to get this `'created',  'modified',` column value and i want to change into japan standard time.I want to edit that `created and modified` column value so where can i edit?
when i assign value to this **despostor view page.** It shown `warning error(Undefined error).`

How to change that value and also,i need a folder where created time value came from.

how is it possible? would you anybody provide solution for this?

Comment: can anybody solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your column has a relation with another table, you can use it like this:

```
array(
  'name' => 'fieldName',
  'value' => '$data->relationName->relatedField',
),
```

and if you want you can manipulate this data like this:

```
array(
  'name' => 'fieldName',
  'value' => 'strtoupper($data->relationName->relatedField)',
),
```

and its better to eager load your data, for performance.
cheers

UPDATE:

if you want to change a value that is displayed in a column,as I said, run it in a function

define a class where you you have a STATIC function, and give your value to it, and make that function return a string (your time zone).

```
 array(
  'name' => 'fieldName',
  'value' => 'TimeClass::changeTime($data->FieldName)',
),
```

thats all